# django model: sort queryset according to ForeignKey attribute

Tags: django-models

Hi I have the following 1:n relation involving A and B and I would like to get a queryset containing all objects of A ordered by the newest date which the corresponding B objects have.

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...


class B(models.Model):
    a = ForeignKey(B)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()
```

Example:

```
A = {a1, a2}

B = {b1 = (a1, 2.4.), b2 = (a1, 1.5.), b3 = (a2, 7.9.), b4 = (a2, 1.1.)}
```

then a2 should be listed before a1 because b3 is newer than the newest date of b1 and b2.

Does anybody know how to do this in django?

Comment: How is `7.9` a date and time?

Comment: its just an example, meaning september 7th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use annotate. See [this sample](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-by):

```
Book.objects.annotate(num_authors=Count('authors')).order_by('num_authors')
```

For your code

```
from django.db.models import Max
your_query_set = (
    A
   .objects
   .annotate( max_data = Max( 'b__date_created' ) )
   .order_by( '-max_data' )
    )
```